# How can I improve this proof?

Tags: proof-writing

I am trying to write a proof that $a \vert b$ if and only if $da \vert db$. This is what I have so far:

> $da \vert db$ if and only if $\lfloor db / da \rfloor = db / da$
>
> $\frac{db}{da} = \frac{b}{a}$ and therefore $\lfloor b / a \rfloor = b / a$
>
> consequently $a \vert b$

I feel like this addresses the *if* but not the *and only if* part of the initial statement. Where do I go from here?

Comment: What is the definition of "$a|b$" you are using?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Fixed the typos. The definition I am using is that $a \vert b$ if $b \mod a = 0$

Comment: Then you better use the definition in your argument, because at the moment, it looks like the definition is $\lfloor b/a\rfloor =b/a$. If this is something that has been previously established, you may want to mention that: "Recall that we previously showed ..." Anyway, you can reorganize your argument:

Comment: $db/da=b/a$, so also $\lfloor b/a\rfloor =\lfloor db/da\rfloor$. It follows that $da|db$ if and only if $\lfloor db/da\rfloor=db/da$ if and only if $\lfloor b/a\rfloor =b/a$ if and only if $a|b$. This presentation covers both directions of the equivalence directly. (It worries me that your approach assumes $a,d$ are different from zero.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo My definition is based on the fact that $a \mod b = a-b \lfloor a/b \rfloor$. If $a-b \lfloor a/b \rfloor = 0$ then $\lfloor a/b \rfloor = a/b$... You are right though that that part of the proof definately needs to be in there. Thanks for your help.  I might end up using Daniel's approach anyway, even though somehow the *zero remainder* definition makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have that $a \mid b$ if there is a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$$b = ak $$

Therefore, if $a \mid b$ then $b = ak$ and so $db = dak$. Thus, $da\mid db$.

If on the other hand, we begin with the assumption that $da \mid db$, that is:

$$db = dak$$

for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then the fact that $a \mid b$ follows by dividing by $d$ as long as $d \neq 0$.

Edit: The other direction is essentially your original proof backwards.

If $a \mid b$ then $\lfloor{db/da}\rfloor =\lfloor{b/a}\rfloor= b/a = db/da$ and thus $da \mid db$.

Comment: that's probably a better approach, thanks